# Запуск части кода по нажатию определенных клавиш

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать так, чтобы запускался кусок кода, когда нажимаются определенные клавиши, например ctrl + alt, но не могу понять/найти как это реализовать.
Пробовал применить pynput, но ничего не вышло, код даже не запускается.
В моем примере, мне необходимо, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал ctrl+alt, выделенный фрагмент текста копировался и далее с ним происходили дальнейшие действия. 
Копирование я пробую реализовать через pyatogui, импортировал как pya.

```
def hotkey (key1, key2):
    if key1 == keyboard.Key.ctrl and key2 == keyboard.Key.alt :
    pyperclip.copy("")
    pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
```

Далее в конце программы запускаю listener

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=hotkey)
listener.start()
```

Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Хоткей должен быть глобальный, но скопированную строку обработать в tk? Добавьте еще пример с tk

Comment: Да. То есть необходимо, чтобы при свернутом интерфейсе, я мог допустим в ворде нажать комбинацию ctrl+alt и оно скопировалось в буфер, а затем из буфера в tk. Не совсем понял насчет примеров, их больше нет ) Я пробовал добавить print('какой-то текст'), чтобы убедиться в том, что функция вообще срабатывает, но она не срабатывает, и я не понимаю почему. Либо listener запущен не правильно, либо не срабатывает условие в функции. Я пробовал и просто отслеживание по одной клавише вместо двух - результат тот же.

Comment: Кажется я нашел решение в обсуждении на гитхабе https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20
Надеюсь в скором времени проверить и отписаться

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print(f'клавиши цифры , буквы  {key.char} нажаты')
    except AttributeError:
        print(f'специальные лавиши {key} нажаты')

def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} нажата клавиша')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Я читал документацию к pynput. Данный код просто прописывает в файле listener все нажатые клавиши. Мне оно не надо.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput import keyboard

# The key combination to check
COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.ctrl_l, keyboard.Key.alt_l}

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()


def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            print('All modifiers active!') #or any function you need
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()


def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Либо более изящное решение с помощью пакета keyboard

```
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt', lambda: your_function_here())
```